# Simple 3D Renders

Tags: 3d

I'm looking for some tips on software, methods etc. that would allow me to quickly do renders like the one shown here (note: I'm a mac user).

I'm aware of the following software packages,

1. Blender
2. Solidworks
3. 3DS Max

and I've given them a shot, but honestly the learning curve is really steep. I'm looking for simple cel shading renders and lighting so that I can illustrate ideas with informative, minimalistic figures.

Do you have any suggestions for software, methods, or anything else that might help me get to quickly making cel shaded, minimalistic figures?

[image: Example render that I would like to be able to do.]

Comment: As it stands this is a very broad question. Photoshop, AutoCAD, Rhino, FormZ, Illustrator, Modo can all do the above image among many other software packages. I'd also point out that the image you posted doesn't look Cel Shaded at all. Voting to close as too broad. If you can edit the question to be something answerable then I'm happy to retract or vote to reopen.

Comment: Hmmm... Okay, whatever you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My 2 free options.

For this simple (and not so simple) renders Blender would be my top choice. I would use internal render in this case.

Another option can be sketchup. It is sometime that I don't use it since it is not from google, but give it a try: http://www.sketchup.com/

It has no render engine, but you can try one from several. I used Kerkythea 
http://www.kerkythea.net/cms/index.php/downloads

Regarding the method, it comes to my mind:
1) Use infinite lights.
2) Use a simple render engine/method.
3) Use a very large focal leight. Blender can give you a non perspective view (isometric if you want).

The obvius part is that you make simple shapes.